# Insect bites vs. stings

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, animales, vocabulario

In English, some insects bite you (like mosquitos), while other insects sting you (like bees). A bite generally involves an animal's mouth, while a sting involves another part of the animal (a bee's or scorpion's stinger).

Is there any way to make this distinction in Spanish, or do all animals *picar*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb *picar* is definitely the most common (in my experience, in Spain) for insect (and related) bites. However, *morder* is also used. For example, Wikipedia shows 211,000 hits for "picadura de araña" vs. 147,000 for "mordedura de araña".

Like in English, *picar* is more associated to a stinger and *morder* to a mandible or biting device. Notice that mosquitoes *pican*, because although they do it for feeding purposes and using their mouth organs, these are needle-shaped and hence *picar*.

BTW, and slightly off-topic, scorpions and spiders are not insects but arachnids. ;-)

With regard to other animals, most people would commonly use *picar* for snakes, but it's more proper to use *morder* in this case. Fish with stingers *pican*, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make this distinction in Spanish, or do all
>   animals picar?

No, not all animals always `pican` but **insects** always `pican,`even the biggest insect.

Comment: I've often heard that "avispas" (wasps) "muerden" or "pican" depending if they use their "mouth" or their sting. Indeed in google some people say that male wasps "muerden" while female wasps "pican". But I'm not an expert in wasps. Anyway, "me ha mordido una avispa" is common in Spain.

Comment: @Javi Thanks for the comment. That's news to me. I would always say: `Me picó una (hdp) avispa` :D